# Website to read list of S3 objects from AWS

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to make a Web page as simple as HTML + simple JS/CSS but it needs to read list of objects (files) from a specific S3 bucket.

Front end part I finished but in order to get a list of s3 objects - I need to issue a command `aws s3 ls` -> in order to get a list of files from S3 but that requires AWS tokens every 1-2h. Or I can run the command from EC2 with adding user to some role and then run from there without tokens.

Ideally website will be hosted on some AWS service (S3, CloudFront...) and not on EC2. 
How to achieve above (without hosting it on EC2)?

Comment: you need to use AWS SDK for browser: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

Comment: Give that you'll either need to supply credentials to the web page or build server-side compute that already has credentials, have you consider simply using the awscli on the client or a tool like Cloudberry Explorer to get the list of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Lambda that generates S3 signed url. That way it will be scalable and secured. You need an external process to create a signed url for you, Lambda is suitable for this purpose.

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key'};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
console.log('The URL is', url);
```

Documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

> CloudFront -- APIGateway -- Lambda

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.. What is 'bucket' in a first line - name of a bucket?

Comment: added documentation reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to grant access to private S3 buckets, after doing access control.

- Using AWS Cognito Federated Identities to federate access to AWS S3.
- Using AWS STS to generate temporary access token by your backend (Generate from EC2 or API Gateway & Lambda).
- Using S3 Signed URLs (Generate from EC2 or API Gateway & Lambda).
- CloudFront Signed URLs or Signed Cookies (Generate from EC2 or API Gateway & Lambda).

For more details refer the article [Upload files Securely to AWS S3 Directly from Browser](https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-signed-urls-fa0a0cf489db).